# Bash file creation from variable

Tags: arrays, xml, string, bash, filenames

I am trying to create files from an array called columnHeaders[]
Within the array, I have test values that are currently:
id, source, EN, EN-GB, French-FR, French-DE

When I run my code I get

EN

EN.xml

EN-GB

EN-GB.xml

French-FR

French-FR.xml

French-DE

.xmlch-DE

NOTE that the FRENCH-DE filename gets morphed into .xmlch-DE
Why is this? I can't for the life of me figure out whey only that file ends up looking like this. It's driving me crazy!
Thanks for any help.

below is the snippet of my code that is causing me problems:

```
# take all the languages and either find the files or create new files for them. The language     options
# should be stored in the columnHeader array in positions 3 - n


# cycle through all the output languages (so exclude "id, source' inputs)
# in my example, numWordsInLine is 6
c=2
while [ $c -lt $numWordsInLine ]; do
    OUTPUT_LANG="${columnHeaders[$c]}"
    echo "$OUTPUT_LANG"
    OUTPUT_FILE="$OUTPUT_LANG".xml

    # HERE'S WHERE YOU CAN SEE OUTPUT_FILE IS WRONG FOR FRENCH_DE
    echo "$OUTPUT_FILE"

    OUTPUT_BAK="$OUTPUT_LANG".bak
    TMP_FILE="~tmp.xml"

    if [ -f "$OUTPUT_BAK" ]; then
            rm "$OUTPUT_BAK"
    fi
    # make a backup of the original language.xml file in case of program error or interruption
    if [ -f "$OUTPUT_FILE" ]; then
            mv "$OUTPUT_FILE" "$OUTPUT_BAK"
    fi

    if [ -f "$TMP_FILE" ]; then
    rm "$TMP_FILE"
    fi

    c=$(expr $c + 1)
done
```

Comment: Show output of `echo ${columnHeaders[@]}`

Comment: code: 
echo "Hi stack overflow"
echo ${columnHeaders[@]}
output:
Hi stack overflow
id source EN EN-GB French-FR French-DE

Comment: as you can see from the output of OUTPUT_LANG, the 'French-DE' is being passed in right and can be called. It's merely the addition of the .xml that is causing problems.

Comment: Please post output of `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `printf "#%s#" ${columnHeaders[@]}`.

Comment: @Cyrus, without more quotes that isn't helpful. `"${columnHeaders[@]}"`, not `${columnHeaders[@]}`, or you get the same result as you would from `${columnHeaders[*]}`.

Comment: ...also, if you wanted to be able to see nonprintable characters, you'd use printf `%q`, not `%s`.

Comment: @kusold, re: code review -- see the automated tool at http://shellcheck.net/, which can catch a great many common errors.

Comment: For me something like `printf "#%s#" ${columnHeaders[@]}` worked fine to determine the existence of \n and/or \r but with %q it is clearly visible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm betting that you are reading that line of data from a file with DOS newlines.

I'm also betting that the contents of the variable are "fine" but include a trailing carriage return.

Try `printf %q\\n "$OUTPUT_FILE"` or `echo "$OUTPUT_FILE" | cat -v` to see.

Then use something like `dos2unix` on the file to convert it.

Extra (unrelated) comments:

There's also no reason to use `expr`. `((c++))` will do what you want.

You could even turn the loop itself into `for ((c=2;c < $numWordsInLine; c++)); do` if you wanted to.

`$numWordsInLine` is also unnecessary if `$columnHeaders` is already split into the right "words" since you can use `${#columnHeaders}` to get the length.

Comment: aha! I believe this is correct. When I tried that I ended up getting: 'French-DE\r.xml'
Is there anyway to remove the \r without using dos2unix?

Comment: also thanks for your code review comments. This is my first bash script and I have been piecing together bits of information. Your comments are really helpful

Comment: You can manually strip it from the file entries if you want to with something like `${OUTPUT_FILE%$'\r'}` but that's more work and you have to be sure to do that every time (or do it once at input/read time and save the modified value). Is there a reason you don't want to modify the file?

Comment: @kusold: add `columnHeaders=(${columnHeaders[@]%$'\r'})` before your while loop to remove DOS newlines from your array elements.

Comment: @Cyrus You need to be careful with quoting. In this case it doesn't matter but that suggestion will word split all the elements of `columnHeaders`. `columnHeaders=("${columnHeaders[@]%$'\r'}")` will avoid that.